# beeline not able to connect to hiveserver2

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I have a CDH 5.3 instance. 
I start the hive-server2 by first starting the hive-metastore and then the hive-server from command line. 
After this I use beeline to connect to my hive-server2 but apparently it is not able to so.

```
Could not open connection to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (state=08S01,code=0)
```

Another issue, I tried to see if the hive-server2 was listening on port 10000. 
I did " `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :10000`" but none of the applications came up.
I also added the following property in the hive-site.xml but to no avail. Why it doesn't show up on the netstat?

```
<property>
   <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
   <value>10000</value>
   <description>TCP port number to listen on, default 10000</description>
 </property>
```

The connect command on beeline:

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

when asked for username and password, I just enter test "user" and "password"
for the respective values and then it throws the error. 
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Share the beeline command you are executing ?

Comment: The reason behind connection refused exception is that the hiveserve2 daemon is not running. Please check hiveserver2 daemon log

Comment: I started the hive-server2 with the " sudo service hive-server2 start " command and it was showing it started.

Answer (score 16):

Hive Connecting to beeline from client having various Modes.

**1.Embedded Mode:**
        Both Server and Client runs in same machine. No TCP Connection required.

```
 If hive.server2.authentication is "NONE" in HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml then connect beeline with below url

Connection URL:
               !connect jdbc:hive2://
```

**2.  Remote Mode:**
        It supports multiple clients to execute queries with help of following Authentication schemes.

Authentication Schemes:

```
i.)SASL Authentication:

   If value of "hive.server2.authentication" property in HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml to be set as "SASL" then connect hive beeline with below url

   Beeline URL:
             !connect jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>

ii.)NOSASL Authentication:
   If "hive.server2.authentication" is nosasl then connect the beeline like below.
   Beeline URL:

             !connect jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>;auth=noSasl
```

Hope this really helps you

References:

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_dataintegration/content/beeline-vs-hive-cli.html

Comment: Great help! My problem was that I didn't put `auth=noSasl` even when I set NOSASL. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here.
This is simply because `hiveserver2` failed to start -- the error does not show up in console, but in hive logs. In my case, hive logs are located in `/tmp/ubuntu/hive.log`

There might be different reason for you to cause `hive-server2` failed to start, but it definitely worth to look into this log file.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me. If you installed and configured hive for the first time and trying to connect from beeline, make sure you start the hive service using the following command  in the current terminal

```
 >hive --service hiverserver2 &
```

The process id for Hiverver2 appears in the console.Then retry connecting to hive from beeline using different terminal:

```
 >beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default" -n <username> -p <password> -d "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
```

Comment: Maybe check this: hive --service hiverserver2 &, there is a typo, instead of hive --service hiveserver2 &

Answer (score 2):

In this case,your hiveserver2 service was not started.please follow blow steps to check and fix.
step：
1.see hive.log file to check "Service:HiveServer2 is started."

```
1) find / -name hive.log
2) vim hive.log
  in hive.log file ,if you can not find "Service:HiveServer2 is started.",then prove hiveserver2 is not started.
```

2.start hiveserver2
  command: ./bin/hiveserver2

3.see hive.log。
  if you can find "Service:HiveServer2 is started." in hive.log. then connect hiveserver2 by beeline.

4.connect hiveserver2
 ./bin/beeline
 !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000

5.below information can appeare.

```
Beeline version 1.2.1 by Apache Hive
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: root
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: ******
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 1.2.1)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give hiveserver2 username and password check it in hive-site.xml by default username(anonymous) and password(anonymous) otherwise just give enter without giving password and username.

Answer (score 0):

try with verbose option so you can see more details...

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default;user=user;password=*******" --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the hive2service deployment IP.

I meet the same problem, I use the cloudera server ip(XXX.42) to connect the hive2 service; but in fact hive thrift service(hive2service) is depoyed on other machine(XXX.41).