# Issue in using beeline to connect to Spark Thrift Server

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-thriftserver

I have started the spark thrift server on port 10015. It started successfully and also I can connect to metastore,but I'm unable to use beeline to connect to Spark thrift server.
Please tell me if I have missed anything.

**-------Process I followed is below ------------**

[root@hadoopdashuju009154 bin]# netstat -an|grep 10015

tcp  0  0 10.2.9.154:10015   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN
  [root@hadoopdashuju009154 bin]#

**- my hive-site.xml under the spark_home conf directory**

```
 <property>
   <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
   <value>10015</value>
   <description>
    Port number of HiveServer2 Thrift interface.  Can be overridden by 
setting $HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_PORT
    </description>
  </property>
 <property>
   <name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name>
   <value>10.2.9.154</value>
   <description>Bind host on which to run the HiveServer2 Thrift interface. 
Can be overridden by setting $HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_BIND_HOST</description>
 </property>
```

**- error when i connect to spark thrift server using beeline**

[root@hadoopdashuju009154 bin]# ./beeline -u 
    jdbc:hive2://hadoopdashuju009154.ppdgdsl.com:10015

```
scan complete in 2ms

Connecting to jdbc:hive2://hadoopdashuju009154.ppdgdsl.com:10015

18/05/23 17:28:57 INFO jdbc.Utils: Supplied authorities: 
hadoopdashuju009154.ppdgdsl.com:10015

18/05/23 17:28:57 INFO jdbc.Utils: Resolved authority: 

hadoopdashuju009154.ppdgdsl.com:10015 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge.getCanonicalHostName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.14.0 by Apache Hive
0: jdbc:hive2://hadoopdashuju009154.ppdgdsl.c (closed)>
```

[root@hadoopdashuju009154 bin]#

Comment: you can find your answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898936/beeline-not-able-to-connect-to-hiveserver2?rq=1

Comment: I mean use spark thrift server instead of hive thrift server,that seems not ok

Comment: Is there any one can give me any sugguestion?

Comment: I have solved that by establish another spark without CDH and download the missing jar and put it to local spark.Thanks